# Create Horizontal and Vertical Scroll View Dynamically Android

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

In my project i managed to display the database in the form of rows and columns of edit Texts and text Views.But the as the number of rows and columns increase it is not possible to view the added data , they dont fit into the screen. 
so i think i needed a horizontal scrollview and a vertical scrollview for viewing entire rows and columns. Below
is my code kindly help me how to achieve this.
Please do help me thanks in advance

xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">



<TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5"
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_weight="1.0">

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The following is the code for page where i wanna display my rows and columns

```
public class ViewActivity extends Activity {
EditText col1;
EditText col2;
TextView Id;
EditText col4;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    HorizontalScrollView hs =new HorizontalScrollView(this);

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

    //CREATING A LIST OF HEADINGS

TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
    tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));

    Id = new TextView(this);
    Id.setText("COL1");
    tr1.addView(Id);

    Id = new TextView(this);
    Id.setText("COL2");
    tr1.addView(Id);

    Id = new TextView(this);
    Id.setText("COL3");
    tr1.addView(Id);

    Id = new TextView(this);
    Id.setText("Rssi");
    tr1.addView(COL4);

    Id = new TextView(this);
    Id.setText("Delete");
    tr1.addView(COL5);

    Id = new TextView(this);
    Id.setText("Update");
    tr1.addView(COL6);

    hs.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));



    tl.addView(tr1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  

    // CREATING ROWS AND COLUMNS DYNAMICALLY


    final DBclass entry = new DBclass(ViewActivity.this);
    entry.open();
    Cursor c = entry.getAllRecords();

    int count =0;

    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setId(count);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));

            /* CODE FOR
              COLUMNS DISPLAYED IN THE FORM OF 
              EDITTEXTS AND TEXTVIEWS
            */

            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));



            count++;
        }while(c.moveToNext());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you could simply put your TableLayout inside a ScrollView to solve this problem. No need to fiddle with adding Views programatically, just predefine it in the XML layout resource. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5"
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_weight="1.0">

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Keep in mind ScrollView is vertical, so you'd need to add a HorizontalScrollView in there to add horizontal scrolling as well.

Comment: is there a way to have diagonal scrolling and not horizontal and vertical scrolling only?